# minimal working example of tikz usage in bookdown?

Tags: r, latex, tikz, bookdown

i have been trying to implement a tikz chunk in bookdown first by myself, then by following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358934/include-tikz-code-in-bookdown-figure-environment).

unfornutately, i keep running into various errors and incompatibilities, such as this one:

> Error in tools::texi2dvi(texf, pdf = !to_svg, clean = TRUE) : 
>     unable to run 'pdflatex' on '.\tikzf702b605920.tex'

(even though by itself `tinytex::pdflatex('test.tex')` works fine)

on his blog and github Yihui Xie mentioned that it's definitely possible, but i wasn't able to find any working example, so i was hoping if perhaps anyone here could share one, please (or point out what am i doing wrong)

Comment: have you been able to figure out this one? I'm running into a similar problem where it says unable to run `latex` (not pdflatex).

Answer (score 0):

@PaulLemmens, i found what was the problem for me. disclaimer here, i use windows and none of my colleagues who use r on linux/macos have this problem.

issue was arising with knitr when engine=tikz is used in one of the chunks. For it to work installation of imagemagick (https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and GhostScript (https://www.ghostscript.com/) is needed. as well as that, i had to rewrite knitr (https://github.com/darthaline/knitr) slightly. it's a quick and dirty solution, but it worked for me. on line 281 of R/engine.R the path to imagemagick's convert is hardcoded cause otherwise it seems that windows interprets it as 'convert.exe' from System32 directory ([ImageMagick PATH not being recognized with engine = "tikz" in knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961773/imagemagick-path-not-being-recognized-with-engine-tikz-in-knitr))